# Parse date/time from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.3. I'm getting an email from an IMAP server, then converting it to an instance of an email from the [standard email library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html).

I do this:

```
message.get("date")
```

Which gives me this for example:

```
Wed, 23 Jan 2011 12:03:11 -0700
```

I want to convert this to something I can put into `time.strftime()` so I can format it nicely. I want the result in local time, not UTC.

There are so many functions, deprecated approaches and side cases, not sure what is the modern route to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
import email, email.utils, datetime, time    

def dtFormat(s):
  dt = email.utils.parsedate_tz(s)
  dt = email.utils.mktime_tz(dt)
  dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt)
  dt = dt.timetuple()
  return dt
```

then this:

```
s = message.get("date")    # e.g. "Wed, 23 Jan 2011 12:03:11 -0700"
print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", dtFormat(s)))
```

gives this:

```
2011-01-23-21-03-11
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
>>> import time
>>> s = "Wed, 23 Jan 2011 12:03:11 -0700"
>>> newtime = time.strptime(s, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S -0700')
>>> print(time.strftime('Two years ago was %Y', newtime))
Two years ago was 2011 # Or whatever output you wish to receive.
```

Comment: Looking for something built-in which doesn't require any string manipulation. This code requires that I hardcode knowledge of the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

I use [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) for parsing datetime strings. Function [parse](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) from this library is very handy for this kind of task